# How to connect to a SQL Server database from another computer using an application I built

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created a very simple application just to test out if I could create an app and then put it on another computer and hit the database on my other computer. I can enter data into my database on the computer that hosts the SQL Server just fine, but on my other computer I get the error message

> Provider: Named pipes Provider, Error 40, could not open a connection to SQL Server

I've done everything on [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-2017) and googled and tried troubleshooting a ton. I am using SQL Server 2017 and VS 2017. Is it something wrong with the host computer or the other computer?

I tried troubleshooting with [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) and after I got to the part about pinging the computer I can't ping the host computer using the other computer and using the other computer I can't ping the host computer. Both ways pinging wouldn't work, but the information on how to troubleshoot that wasn't very good.

Comment: This question looks like a question about server configuration, not programming. You may want to consider deleting this question and checking to see if it is on topic for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Try (temporarily) disabling the firewall on your server

Comment: This is network issue and wrongly asked as a database question.

Answer (score 0):

I found something may be helpful from google...

According to users, if you're unable to ping other computers, the issue might be related to your network. To fix the problem, be sure that your PCs are properly connected and able to access the Internet. In addition, you might want to try restarting your network devices and check if that solves the issue

https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-unable-to-ping-other-computers/

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to: 
1. Enable access through firewall
2. Specify a port to connect to the computer hosting the database.
3. Make sure you are on the same network and can connect each other via localhost. If you cannot access via the default 127.0.0.1, try connecting by the ip address of the computer that is hosting your database.

If proper firewall access and ip config are not maintained, you will not be able to connect to the DB. It is appropriate running a REST server configuration on the host machine to allow access to the data through API requests rather than direct access to the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi,
>
> I had same problem while connecting sql server via developement
>   server.
>
> In my case there was a problem with sql port (1433) blocked from
>   firewall.
>
> Please do below given steps to check the same in your machine.
>
> I hope it will work for u.
>
> 1 > open cmd and ping your server IP
>
> for example
>
> c:\System32>ping 192.168.1.45 -t
>
> 2> check sql port(1433) is open for your sql sever by using telnet
>
> for example : telnet server IP port Number
>
> c:\System32> telnet 192.168.1.45 1433
>
> 3 > if telenet failed... then use below command to open the port OR
>   contact your network team.
>
> c:\System32> netsh firewall set portopening protocol = TCP port = 1433 name =
>   SQLPort mode = ENABLE scope = SUBNET profile = CURRENT